# Meaning of "registered with him"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could someone please help me with the meaning of the bold part in the text below?

> He had been in the office when the accident happened, consulting with
> a veneer salesman. **Some change in noise registered with him, but it
> was more of an increase than a hush.** It was nothing that alerted
> him—just an irritation. Because it happened in the sawmill, nobody
> would know about the accident immediately in the shops or in the kilns
> or in the yard, and work in some places continued for several minutes.
> In fact Arthur, bending over the veneer samples on his desk, might
> have been one of the last people to understand that there had been an
> intervention. He asked the salesman a question, and the salesman did
> not answer. Arthur looked up and saw the man's mouth open, his face
> frightened, his salesman's assurance wiped away.
>
> <sub>**Carried Away** by Alice Munro</sub>

The way that **register** is used in the text is not what I am used to. Would you please tell me if it's a common usage?

Comment: You could reformulate the sentence saying: " He realised there was a change in the noise but ....".  
[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/register#register_13) definition 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register in this case means that he became aware of the noise. It is reasonably common and can be found in most definitions of the word.

> Register
>
> 1. express or convey (an opinion or emotion).
>      "I wish to register an objection"
>
> synonyms:   display, show, express, exhibit, evince, betray, disclose, evidence, reveal, manifest, demonstrate, reflect, bespeak, testify to; literary, betoken
>
> "her face registered gathering anger"
>   (of an emotion) show in a person's face or gestures.
>
> "nothing registered on their faces"
>
> **notice or become aware of.**
>
> "he hadn't even registered her presence"